# How to remove the Firebase Cloud Messaging SDK from Unity?

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, unity-game-engine, firebase-cloud-messaging

I want to display an Android notification with a large image whenever I send a notification from FCM (I have included the data payload with a URL for the image). The Android app can be in background or foreground.

I did not know earlier that this is not directly possible with the Unity SDK for FCM. So now I have a Unity project which I'll need to export the project to Android Studio and do something, according to this thread: https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-unity/issues/146#issuecomment-389579086

What I've figured is (maybe I'm wrong) I'll need to remove the FCM SDK from Unity and add the Android SDK in Android Studio and follow the steps for Android. So I deleted all the FCM specific files from my project, reimported other SDKs (Firebase Database, Firebase Auth, Firebase Analytics, Firebase Remote Config, Facebook SDK and GoogleMobileAds SDK) to ensure I didnt break any of these SDKs in the process.
Before exporting to Android Studio, I tried building directly from Unity to make sure I'm making stable builds, but the app crashes as soon as I open it. This is probably happening because the Messaging SDK has irreversibly changed the entry point to a MessagingUnityPlayerActivity, and I have already deleted it.

How do I safely remove the Messaging SDK? Or is there any other solution to my problem?